# Написание Unit-тестов

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit

Добрый день.

Я только начинаю разбираться в юнит-тестировании, и у меня есть вопрос по созданию юнит-тестов.

Вопрос больше на логику, наверное.

У меня будет 4 метода:

1. Загрузка матрицы с файла в двумерный массив `GetMatrix(string filename)`;
2. Метод, с помощю которого матрица разворачивается на 90 градусов — `void RotateMatrix()`;
3. Метод вывода матрицы на экран — `void ToScreen()`;
4. Сохранение матрицы в файл.

Мне нужно в этом проекте написать 2 юнит-теста.

Вопрос: как лучше реализовать тесты? Какую логику использовать? Что проверять?

Спасибо!

Comment: >Что проверять?

Ну собственно, то, что хотите реализовать, то и проверяйте - то, что матрица успешно загрузилась, что она корректно поворачивается, что сохранение ее в файл проходит успешно.

Comment: А можно немного конкретней?   
Просто я понимаю, как сделать проверку в методах загрузки/сохранения с помощью try/catch. А вот с помощью юнит-тестов - пока не очень.

Comment: @Telsystems, поконкретнее вам стоит прочесть какое-нибудь руководство по юнит-тестированию. Не то, чтобы это очень уж объемная тема, но все же она вне рамок одного ответа или тем более комментария. 
Вкратце: создаете тестовый проект с классами для тестов, в каждом конкретном методе этих классов проверяете с помощью ассертов (и/или какой-то собственной логики) соответствие поведения вашей бизнес-логики задачам, возлагаемым на эту логику. Прогоняете тесты с разными данными, как корректными, так и некорректными.